# Is QPainter::setPen function expensive?

Tags: qt, user-interface, qt5, 2d

My code draws a line which consists of several segments and circles on vertices.

```
void Line::paintLine(QPainter* painter, const std::vector<QPointF>& line)
{
    QBrush brush(m_fillColor);
    painter->setBrush(brush);
    painter->setOpacity(m_opacity);

    QPen pen(m_lineColor, 1);

    painter->setPen(Qt::NoPen);
    painter->drawEllipse(line[0], CircleRadius, CircleRadius);

    for (int i = 1; i < line.size(); ++i)
    {
        painter->setPen(Qt::NoPen);
        painter->drawEllipse(line[i], CircleRadius, CircleRadius);

        painter->setPen(pen);
        painter->drawLine(line[i-1], line[i]);
    }
}
```

I call QPainter::setPen many times inside for loop. Is this good in terms performance? Is QPainter::setPen quick function? (I know that material switching in 3D graphics is slow operation but probably it is not true for 2D GUI drawing.)
Or maybe separate loops are more optimal?

```
void Line::paintLine(QPainter* painter, const std::vector<QPointF>& line)
{
    QBrush brush(m_fillColor);
    painter->setBrush(brush);
    painter->setOpacity(m_opacity);

    QPen pen(m_lineColor, 1);

    painter->setPen(Qt::NoPen);
    for (int i = 0; i < line.size(); ++i)
        painter->drawEllipse(line[i], CircleRadius, CircleRadius);

    painter->setPen(pen);
    for (int i = 1; i < line.size(); ++i)
        painter->drawLine(line[i-1], line[i]);
}
```

Comment: Did you try to profile your code?

Answer (score 0):

For sure changing then pen is not that expensive. But if it's possible, separate your loops to minimize pen changes. When you are changing the pen, [DirtyPen](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpaintengine.html#DirtyFlag-enum) flag will be set in [QPaintEngine](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpaintengine.html) which then forces potential tasks to be done before the next paint command. You should profile it in your own implementation to see how many micro-seconds you will save by separating loops.